# Make a label or button behave as a checkbox?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, boolean, label

I want code that when you click a label it changes a `Boolean` to `True`, if it was `False` and to `False` if it was `True`.
And it can loop, like a checkbox.

```
Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
    Dim clickedLabel = TryCast(sender, Label)
    If bool1 = True Then
        If clickedLabel IsNot Nothing Then
            bool1 = False
    End If
    If bool1 = False Then
        If clickedLabel IsNot Nothing Then
            bool1 = True
    End If
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just handle the `Click` event of the label.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _MyBool As Boolean

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        _MyBool = Not _MyBool
        Label1.Text = IIf(_MyBool, "MyBool is true", "MyBool is false")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Using the `not` operator is an easy way to toggle a boolean value - whatever it was, the `not` operator will flip it.  Otherwise, the only problem with the code you have is that you are missing `End If` statements for your `if bool1 = ...` sections.